# Disk Cleanup utility on ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, disk-image

This question is influenced by the diskclean utility in Windows.

Is there a tool (and a need) to perform the task.  I tend to used when imaging a hard disk.

Thank you

Comment: In Kubuntu: Sweeper can quickly remove temporary information, such as web page cookies,
browser history, or the list of recently-opened documents. This package is part of the KDE SC utilities module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could try using [Bleachbit](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bleachbit/). It is the most similar to CCleaner.
   It can delete your browser history old outdated kernel images etc... But i don't know if it can identify unneeded config files. Even so you always have the option to also purge any left config if you uninstall something via commandline, and as well as install the default config of anything if reinstalling something, and that with just the normal command line apt.
2. Do you need to use it. From my experience not really. I mostly used CCleaner because the default windows uninstall tool is slow nowadays, because you might even run into more problems if you delete too much still necessary information.

Comment: I am happy with the performance of my system. I don't want to break anything.
It might be wiser to leave everything as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu Cleaner - a software designed exactly for the job of cleaning up a system so it becomes more like a freshly installed one.

This can be achieved by following these simple steps in Terminal.

```
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gerardpuig/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-cleaner
```

Access the utility from the system dashboard or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (usually left Windows key by default) and begin typing *cleaner* into the search box.

[image]

You can uninstall it if you wish by entering the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-cleaner && sudo apt autoremove
```

[additional reference](https://itsubuntu.com/install-ubuntu-cleaner-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: My idea is to remove dead fluff.  In Windows this is mainly Temp folder and Windows updates changed files.

Comment: Sounds good to use ubuntu-cleaner then. OId kernels and apt cache is basically the equivalent to temp files on windows.